# How can I concatenate two strings pointed to by void pointers when the length is known?

Tags: c++

Given the below example:

```
const void * x = "Foo";
size_t xLength = 3;

const void * y = "Bar";
size_t yLength = 3;
```

Is there an effective way I can concatenate the data pointed to, (i.e. to produce `"FooBar"`) without first copying both sets of data into two individual `std::string`s? That's the only solution that comes to mind, but I feel like there must be a more efficient way to achieve what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you end up in this situation?

Comment: convert to char pointers and then copy them into a big enough buffer?

Comment: Null terminated strings are usually expected to be stored in a contiguous array. This is required if you intend to refer to that string using a simple pointer. And since your strings currently reside in their own storage there is no way to perform this concatenation such that a pointer could refer to that resulting string without copying the partial strings at least once.

Comment: As Francois said, no. If it wasn't const, then you could realloc one of the arrays, so long as you remember to free the data afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to copy to individual `std::string`. Just cast to `const char*`

```
const void * x = "Foo";
size_t xLength = 3;

const void * y = "Bar";
size_t yLength = 3;    

std::string foobar(static_cast<const char*>(x), xLength);
foobar.append(static_cast<const char*>(y), yLength);
```